# Create a extension for civicrm

Tags: civix

Please give some reference site for creating a simple extension for civicrm with sample example.
Any simple extension on GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install [civix](https://github.com/totten/civix/blob/master/README.md) to create civicrm extension and then follow [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-module) for creating module extension. There are many examples of [extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions) under civicrm.org. The easiest one to start would be

- https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-key
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/phone-number-validator
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/show-contact-deceased
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/sms-api
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-logging-report
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/olark-chat
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/birthdays-month
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/show-member-ids
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/mysms-mantra-sms-gateway-integration
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-country-manager

Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrk8X_jt0wU

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Hello Pradip sir, do you create any extension ?

Comment: Yes I do create them based on clients requirement.

Comment: Please I want to learn those things?

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrk8X_jt0wU

Answer (score 1):

As a first step I would go check the Developer Guide here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/

Comment: Actually I tried it from last 4 days. I install civix also. I want to create simple question and answer web form. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want the form to be in CiviCRM or on the website? Do you understand the relationship between your website and CiviCRM?

Comment: have you thought about doing this via the CMS eg Caldera (WP) or Webform (D)?

Answer (score 0):

1. First install civix and create a extension in `[civicrm.files]/ext/` folder. The extensions folder will have all the extension you create in future.
2. Move to that extension folder and generate a new extension by executing `civix generate:module <your_extension_name> --license=AGPL-3.0` command.